# Merge [tag:geary] into [tag:pantheon-mail]

Tags: discussion, tags

[geary](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geary) is now [pantheon-mail](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-mail) so the two should be combined into one tag to preempt any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been linked and merged.